# Formatting Dates in R with times in the same column

Tags: r

I have a file that gives me the date along with the time in the column.

I only want the date, but in Year-month-day format.

```
vmax1$date <- substr(vmax1$date,1,10)
```

myformat <- "%y-%m-%d"
vmax1$date<-as.Date(vmax1$date,myformat)
str(vmax1)

Here is the code I use, but it just changes the date column to NAs instead of the correct format
[image]

Comment: The format should match the one in the data.  It should be `%d/%m/%Y` and not `%y-%m-%d` where %d stands for day, %m- month and %Y- four digit year

Comment: When I do that it changes the day of the month to the  year? How to I fix that?

Comment: I am not able to replicate `as.Date('19/03/2021 10:05', '%d/%m/%Y')#
[1] "2021-03-19"`